# find in column distinguishing between empty and blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find the first cell in a column that's either empty or contains only blanks.  I came up with the following..

```
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Done As Boolean

FindString = ""
With Sheets("Yahoo").Range("A:A")
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells([Stock_Start_Row], 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        j = Rng.Row
        Done = False
        Do Until Done
            FindString = .Cells(j, 1)
            FindString = Replace(FindString, " ", "")
            If FindString = "" Then
                j = j - 1
            Else
                Done = True
            End If
        Loop

        MsgBox "Found" & " " & Rng.Row & " " & j
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End With
```

This will discover and clear any blank cells immediately before the first empty cell but will not discover blank cells among the preceding cells.

Is there any way to search for cells containing one or more blanks?

If so I could add a second search.

Comment: when you say `contains any blanks` do you mean the text in the cell contains a `space`? or you are just looking for blank cells in a column?

Comment: Why not just autofilter the column for zero length cells?

Comment: @scott: I want to find the first cell the 'looks' blank to the users, I.e. is empty or contains ONLY one or more blanks.

Comment: @brettdj: Does a criteria of "=" find empty cells?  cells containing ONLY oneor more blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to find the first cell in a column that's either empty or
>   contains only blanks.

This will go through column A on sheet("Yahoo"). It should work for you:

```
Sub FindBlankOrEmptyCells()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)

Dim cell As Range

Dim BlankCounter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim OldCellValue As Variant ' just for the heck of it

For Each cell In Sheets("Yahoo").Range("A:A")
    OldCellValue = cell.Value
    cell.NumberFormat = "@"
    cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value

    BlankCounter = 0

    If cell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Found an empty cell in Column A, Row: " & " " & cell.Row
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 1 To Len(cell)
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = " " Then
            BlankCounter = BlankCounter + 1
        End If

        If BlankCounter = Len(cell) Then
            MsgBox "Found a cell full of blanks in Column A, Row: " & " " & cell.Row

                cell.Clear
                cell.Value = OldCellValue
                cell.Value = cell.Value

            Exit Sub
            ' If you want to delete the contents of the cell or continue looping you can delete this Exit Sub and put in:
            ' cell.ClearContents
            ' then it will loop through all the cells and delete blanks and message you each time
        End If
    Next i

    cell.Clear
    cell.Value = OldCellValue
    cell.Value = cell.Value

Next cell

End Sub
```

This will find the first cell that is either empty or contains only blanks(spaces). It will stop once it finds a cell that meets that criteria. If you want to continue looping you can enable the code I commented out. Let me know how it works.

EDIT:

If you want to use the .find function to gain some efficiency that is possible - but eventually you are going to need to loop through all the characters in a cell and determine if it contains all spaces. Try this one out(I stopped it at row 30 so it doesn't keep popping up messages for blanks - but you could remove the messages and extend to Loop Until to row 999999):

```
Sub FindBlankOrEmptyCellsWithFindFunction()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Sheets("Yahoo").Range("A1")
Dim Done As Boolean

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)

Dim cell As Range

Dim BlankCounter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim LoopStopperRange As Range
Dim OldCellValue As Variant

ii = 0

Do
    ii = ii + 1
    FindString = " "
    With Sheets("Yahoo").Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(Rng.Row, 1), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then ' If Rng Is Something Then
            If ii = 1 Then
                Set LoopStopperRange = Rng
            End If
            If LoopStopperRange = Rng And ii > 1 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            For Each cell In Rng
                OldCellValue = cell.Value
                cell.NumberFormat = "@"
                cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value

                BlankCounter = 0

                If cell.Value = "" Then
                    MsgBox "Found an empty cell in Column A, Row: " & " " & cell.Row
                    'Exit Sub
                End If

                For i = 1 To Len(cell)
                    If cell.Characters(i, 1).Text = " " Then
                        BlankCounter = BlankCounter + 1
                    End If

                    If BlankCounter = Len(cell) Then
                        MsgBox "Found a cell full of blanks in Column A, Row: " & " " & cell.Row

                            cell.Clear
                            cell.Value = OldCellValue
                            cell.Value = cell.Value

                        'Exit Sub
                        ' If you want to delete the contents of the cell or continue looping you can delete this Exit Sub and put in:
                        ' cell.ClearContents
                        ' then it will loop through all the cells and delete blanks
                    End If

                Next i

                cell.Clear
                cell.Value = OldCellValue
                cell.Value = cell.Value

            Next cell
         Else
        End If
    End With
Loop Until Rng Is Nothing

Set Rng = Sheets("Yahoo").Range("A1")

Do
    ii = ii + 1
    FindString = ""
    With Sheets("Yahoo").Range("A:A")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(Rng.Row, 1), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then ' If Rng Is Something Then
            For Each cell In Rng
                OldCellValue = cell.Value
                cell.NumberFormat = "@"
                cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value

                BlankCounter = 0

                If cell.Value = "" Then
                    MsgBox "This loop will go until Row 30 so you don't have to pause/break out. Found an empty cell in Column A, Row: " & " " & cell.Row
                    'Exit Sub
                End If

            Next cell
         Else
        End If
    End With
Loop Until Rng.Row = 30
'Loop Until Rng.Row = 99999

End Sub
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Edited - Forgot to reset BlankCounter at beginning of loop. Will work better now.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to replace similar code with the use of find for efficiency purposes.  Wonder if there anyway to find a cell containing one or more blanks or better yet a cell that is either empty or contains one or more blanks.

Comment: Robbie: [takes a deep breath, sighs] Gee, you know that information... really would've been more useful to me *yesterday.* - Just Kidding - That's a good quote though. Other than just specifically writing it out repeatedly: FindString = Replace(FindString, " ", "") and so on . . . FindString = Replace(FindString, " "space""space""space"", "") I think I will have to let someone else provide a method using .find

Comment: See my edit - I figured you could probably put my sub within your sub. So it gains efficiency by using .find to find cells with spaces/blanks/empty and then loops through each character in the cell to determine if they are all spaces(or empty). Eventually you are going to have to loop through each character in a cell to determine if it is all spaces - I don't think there is any way around that.

Comment: It sure looks to me that str = replace (str, " ". "") will eliminate all blanks in a string.

Comment: Hey Mike, The easiest way to get rid of all spaces in a range of cells is to just do a find and replace. I recorded this macro:     Cells.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False                                               I could be wrong but I think it is the most efficient too. It will replace all spaces(blanks) with nothing. It will catch cells that contain only spaces and and cells that contain strings that have spaces in them.